# Get an DOM element in the map google div

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

it's possible to get template text from 'childDiv' id when I initialize a Google Map? My code looks like this:

```js
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());
```

```css
#map {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map">
  <div id="childDiv">testes</div>
</div>
```

When I debug this code after initialize map function, that my childDiv gone.

---

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ce4bpzhh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default way the google maps works. It will overwrite the contents of the div you specify for it.

There is an option, however, to tell it to keep the existing contents.

The option is `noClear` and you must set it to `true`.

---

From the Google maps documentation about [`mapOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions)

> **noClear -    Type:  boolean**
>   If `true`, do not clear the contents of the Map div.

---

Working example

```js
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    noClear:true // ADD THIS OPTION
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());
```

```css
#map {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map">
  <div id="childDiv">testes</div>
</div>
```